# Why I can't use multiple columns in a GROUP BY query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1064

I need to make a sql that groups by three different columns, this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    notification.type, 
    notification.triggerer, 
    notification.to_what,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.name) AS name,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.surname) AS surname,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.avatarimage) AS avatarimage,
    COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM notification 
INNER JOIN user_data
    ON notification.triggerer = user_data.owner
WHERE notification.owner = "c6cecc891f6c4cc84cc0b62062578e52"
    AND isdelete=0
ORDER BY notification.id DESC
GROUP BY notification.triggerer, notification.type, notification.to_what
LIMIT 0,100
```

But when I make this, it shows me an error:

```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'GROUP BY notification.triggerer, notification.type, notification.to_what
LIMIT ' at line 15
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but your your `group by` must be before `order by`

```
SELECT 
    notification.type, 
    notification.triggerer, 
    notification.to_what,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.name) AS name,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.surname) AS surname,
    ANY_VALUE(user_data.avatarimage) AS avatarimage,
    COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM notification 
INNER JOIN user_data
    ON notification.triggerer = user_data.owner
WHERE notification.owner = "c6cecc891f6c4cc84cc0b62062578e52"
    AND isdelete=0
GROUP BY notification.triggerer, notification.type, notification.to_what
ORDER BY notification.id DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: I would like to send you +1, but my rank does not allow me :( .. However, really thank you for your answer

Comment: @NicolasMozo You are welcome. You can accept the answer. That is enough ;)